# why use "i" in (Python deleting lines with characters)

Tags: python

I am looking (python deleting lines with characters ways) =.

The code I found is:

```
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin, -4):
    if i>=0:
        print line
```

I don't know why you use '`i`' in the code above.

I already know ' `enumerate` `-4` ' means that delete four head rows.

But i don't know why use '`i`'

Comment: It's just a standard iterator variable.  You can replace i with anything and it will work the same.

Comment: @BTroy  Why do I get an error if I configure the code except for ** 'i' and 'if i>=0' ** ?

Comment: "I already know ' enumerate -4 ' means that delete four head rows." No, that's not what it means. `-4` is the starting value of `i`, by default it is `0` if you don't pass the second argument to `enumerate`. That should give you a hint of what the code is doing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. I fully understand.